# How to redirect the page after payment has been done using paypal

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, paypal, paypal-sandbox

In my webpage i have done the payment process of paypal. I have now able to do the payment process. But now my question is how can i redirect to the action method after the verification is success. Any help is appreciated.

Regards,
Avinash

Answer (score 2):

What I think is after making the payment and confirmation you should redirect to the page you want to go with data you enters or you can use ajax to go to action method.

If you are using "Buy Now" button or "express checkout API" than you can define the return url in "Paypal account" for "Buy now" button and define the return url for "express checkout API"

Answer (score 0):

You can set auto return true in your paypal account see [link](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/mer/express_return_summary-outside) for more description

Comment: Yah i have set that. My doubt is will it return to the same action method that has used initially. i have already tried that but it is not returning to the action result